# How to make a shape bigger relevant to its position - SVG

Tags: matlab, svg

How can I make a shape, specifically a `path` bigger, relevant to its position. There is something called `scale` but it doesn't help me because it's based on x and y which makes the shape bigger relevant to the corner. I want the shape to be zoomed in, from where it's placed, from its center.

Edit: I don't have the positions of the shapes. I have the shapes with their `d` attribute but I don't know how to read the centers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you'll be using javascript for that. Are you using any javascript SVG library or framework already?

Comment: @MehdiElFadi No, I'm not using JS. I just need to be able to change SVG files (XML) in my program, which is in Matlab.

Comment: Then calculate the zoom level according to x and y coordinates in matlab, and use the resulting value inside the path's transform.scale

Comment: @MehdiElFadil That's brilliant but I just want to change the SVG file in Matlab. Matlab isn't creating the SVGs.

Answer (score 1):

Transformation commands in SVG `transform` attributes can be concatenated - they are after all only matrices. What you can do is first `translate` the object to the origin of the coordinate system, then `scale` it, and then `translate` it back.

Suppose the center of your element is at (20, 30) and you want to zoom by factor 2.5. This is executed right to left (read it as a matrix multiplication):

```
transform="translate(20, 30) scale(2.5) translate(-20, -30)"
```

You can also compute the transformation matrix yourself and write:

```
transform="matrix(2.5,0,0,2.5,-30,-45)"
```

The description of these matrices is [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformMatrixDefined).

In theory, with [CSS transforms](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1) it should be much easier to to this. Unfortunately, browser support is not what it should be.

The following example works in Chrome, but not in Firefox (see this [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1209061) for a squabble about what is the right behaviour), IE or Edge. Stand-alone renderers also probably will fail (I falsified with librsvg and Inkscape). The green duck should be half the size of the yellow one and have the same center:

```css
  path {
      fill: none;
      stroke: yellow;
  }
  #tr {
    transform: scale(0.5);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    stroke: green;
  }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
  <path d="M 80.1339,33.7725 A 5.6922,6.4401 10 0 1 84.6212,41.103 5.6922,6.4401 10 0 1 77.8974,46.4568 5.6922,6.4401 10 0 1 73.4101,39.1262 5.6922,6.4401 10 0 1 80.1339,33.7725 Z M 82.0104,33.2778 A 11.4192,8.81609 89.1419 0 1 89.2916,46.4615 11.4192,8.81609 89.1419 0 1 79.1684,55.7873 11.4192,8.81609 89.1419 0 1 71.8879,42.6048 11.4192,8.81609 89.1419 0 1 82.0104,33.2778 Z M 70.3671,75.3594 C 70.3671,75.3594 68.586,75.6931 67.6718,75.6488 66.3528,75.5858 65.0527,74.9422 63.7318,74.8554 59.5513,74.5845 55.4963,76.5847 51.338,75.751 49.2598,75.3338 46.915,74.5923 45.4932,72.8885 44.8341,72.1001 44.3774,70.8894 44.6455,69.9567 45.3964,67.3505 50.7912,65.0483 50.7912,65.0483 50.7912,65.0483 43.9322,61.4587 41.1061,58.7996 38.902,56.7243 36.8574,54.2568 35.6903,51.4657 34.9382,49.6678 34.0963,47.4509 34.8214,45.7744 38.1361,41.2573 43.6807,43.9856 48.4204,45.1849 50.2853,45.6599 52.1398,46.8724 53.9981,46.6994 56.7267,46.4454 58.9343,44.5042 61.1832,43.0426 63.0639,41.8215 66.407,38.8022 66.407,38.8022 66.407,38.8022 64.6497,42.5145 64.3908,44.5758 64.1223,46.7147 64.4954,48.9637 64.9058,51.1399 65.3999,53.7626 66.3032,56.3275 67.233,58.8573 68.3474,61.8899 70.6024,64.6149 71.1153,67.7638 71.5329,70.3313 70.3671,75.3594 70.3671,75.3594 Z M 92.0698,111.853 C 96.2371,106.866 102.147,102.36 108.753,101.964 118.689,101.368 127.519,112.44 137.557,113.607 146.856,114.686 164.63,109.061 164.63,109.061 164.63,109.061 162.709,125.647 158.397,132.099 153,140.178 144.607,146.556 135.357,149.419 127.645,151.807 118.626,151.276 110.573,148.601 103.65,146.302 96.4513,142.201 92.0379,136.07 89.1835,132.103 87.9619,126.816 88.1408,122.105 88.2839,118.339 89.7715,114.602 92.0698,111.853 Z M 59.2917,139.294 C 61.9445,152.369 70.7633,164.205 81.6223,170.584 100.669,181.776 125.118,181.36 145.114,176.023 160.645,171.877 176.151,163.182 185.972,150.351 176.606,158.799 164.621,164.73 152.614,167.936 132.62,173.272 108.172,173.689 89.1233,162.496 78.2648,156.116 70.8095,151.141 68.1586,138.066 66.9416,125.527 79.8773,92.7348 77.4125,94.0907 74.9457,95.445 56.1332,122.504 59.2917,139.294 Z M 65.8609,39.1294 C 70.807,28.9425 79.9895,21.2775 90.0829,19.1926 112.001,16.8358 127.033,28.7634 131.73,48.0754 133.639,55.9048 132.499,64.4111 129.685,71.5142 127.542,76.9213 118.907,84.7996 118.907,84.7996 L 113.696,88.961 C 113.696,88.961 124.423,86.1023 129.998,86.5796 137.334,87.207 144.159,92.3433 151.484,93.3861 153.944,93.7365 156.655,94.179 158.824,93.1744 162.32,91.5568 164.447,87.8071 166.49,84.4927 168.56,81.135 167.572,75.2572 170.993,73.3938 173.665,71.9378 177.805,72.9562 180.38,75.0348 188.826,81.8552 191.576,94.4359 193.393,105.027 195.625,118.046 196.35,132.764 190.351,143.692 181.279,160.216 163.201,171.195 145.113,176.024 125.117,181.361 100.67,181.776 81.6235,170.584 70.7644,164.204 61.9435,152.369 59.2917,139.294 V 139.294 C 57.7803,120.107 70.3787,106.356 76.2899,91.5133 77.2688,88.9676 78.3913,83.5238 78.3913,83.5238 74.9247,81.427 72.0301,78.643 69.6902,75.4715" />
  <path id="tr" d="M 80.1339,33.7725 A 5.6922,6.4401 10 0 1 84.6212,41.103 5.6922,6.4401 10 0 1 77.8974,46.4568 5.6922,6.4401 10 0 1 73.4101,39.1262 5.6922,6.4401 10 0 1 80.1339,33.7725 Z M 82.0104,33.2778 A 11.4192,8.81609 89.1419 0 1 89.2916,46.4615 11.4192,8.81609 89.1419 0 1 79.1684,55.7873 11.4192,8.81609 89.1419 0 1 71.8879,42.6048 11.4192,8.81609 89.1419 0 1 82.0104,33.2778 Z M 70.3671,75.3594 C 70.3671,75.3594 68.586,75.6931 67.6718,75.6488 66.3528,75.5858 65.0527,74.9422 63.7318,74.8554 59.5513,74.5845 55.4963,76.5847 51.338,75.751 49.2598,75.3338 46.915,74.5923 45.4932,72.8885 44.8341,72.1001 44.3774,70.8894 44.6455,69.9567 45.3964,67.3505 50.7912,65.0483 50.7912,65.0483 50.7912,65.0483 43.9322,61.4587 41.1061,58.7996 38.902,56.7243 36.8574,54.2568 35.6903,51.4657 34.9382,49.6678 34.0963,47.4509 34.8214,45.7744 38.1361,41.2573 43.6807,43.9856 48.4204,45.1849 50.2853,45.6599 52.1398,46.8724 53.9981,46.6994 56.7267,46.4454 58.9343,44.5042 61.1832,43.0426 63.0639,41.8215 66.407,38.8022 66.407,38.8022 66.407,38.8022 64.6497,42.5145 64.3908,44.5758 64.1223,46.7147 64.4954,48.9637 64.9058,51.1399 65.3999,53.7626 66.3032,56.3275 67.233,58.8573 68.3474,61.8899 70.6024,64.6149 71.1153,67.7638 71.5329,70.3313 70.3671,75.3594 70.3671,75.3594 Z M 92.0698,111.853 C 96.2371,106.866 102.147,102.36 108.753,101.964 118.689,101.368 127.519,112.44 137.557,113.607 146.856,114.686 164.63,109.061 164.63,109.061 164.63,109.061 162.709,125.647 158.397,132.099 153,140.178 144.607,146.556 135.357,149.419 127.645,151.807 118.626,151.276 110.573,148.601 103.65,146.302 96.4513,142.201 92.0379,136.07 89.1835,132.103 87.9619,126.816 88.1408,122.105 88.2839,118.339 89.7715,114.602 92.0698,111.853 Z M 59.2917,139.294 C 61.9445,152.369 70.7633,164.205 81.6223,170.584 100.669,181.776 125.118,181.36 145.114,176.023 160.645,171.877 176.151,163.182 185.972,150.351 176.606,158.799 164.621,164.73 152.614,167.936 132.62,173.272 108.172,173.689 89.1233,162.496 78.2648,156.116 70.8095,151.141 68.1586,138.066 66.9416,125.527 79.8773,92.7348 77.4125,94.0907 74.9457,95.445 56.1332,122.504 59.2917,139.294 Z M 65.8609,39.1294 C 70.807,28.9425 79.9895,21.2775 90.0829,19.1926 112.001,16.8358 127.033,28.7634 131.73,48.0754 133.639,55.9048 132.499,64.4111 129.685,71.5142 127.542,76.9213 118.907,84.7996 118.907,84.7996 L 113.696,88.961 C 113.696,88.961 124.423,86.1023 129.998,86.5796 137.334,87.207 144.159,92.3433 151.484,93.3861 153.944,93.7365 156.655,94.179 158.824,93.1744 162.32,91.5568 164.447,87.8071 166.49,84.4927 168.56,81.135 167.572,75.2572 170.993,73.3938 173.665,71.9378 177.805,72.9562 180.38,75.0348 188.826,81.8552 191.576,94.4359 193.393,105.027 195.625,118.046 196.35,132.764 190.351,143.692 181.279,160.216 163.201,171.195 145.113,176.024 125.117,181.361 100.67,181.776 81.6235,170.584 70.7644,164.204 61.9435,152.369 59.2917,139.294 V 139.294 C 57.7803,120.107 70.3787,106.356 76.2899,91.5133 77.2688,88.9676 78.3913,83.5238 78.3913,83.5238 74.9247,81.427 72.0301,78.643 69.6902,75.4715" />
</svg>
```

Comment: And what if I don't have the centers? The `path`s have a `d` attribute with a big value which I don't understand. Do you know a simpler solution?

Comment: I can't run the SVG files in browsers, wouldn't be useful for me. I just need to edit the SVG files.

Comment: Then maybe you should mention the renderer in your question.